# iPhone NSThread Help

Tags: iphone, nsthread

I'm having some problems with my thread. Currently, the view brought up by `showInstructions` is disabled until the thread is done... how can I make it interactive while the thread is going on?

Thanks in advance!

```
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(loadEverything) withObject:self waitUntilDone:YES];


    -(void)loadEverything {    
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

        [self performSelector:@selector(showInstructions)];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadStats)];
        [self performSelector:@selector(animate_sideBTN)];
        [self performSelector:@selector(loadNIBs)];
        [self performSelector:@selector(incrementStats)];

        [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadMap) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

        [[self.view viewWithTag: 123] removeFromSuperview];
        [pool drain];
        }
```

Comment: You are calling that method on a new thread, but you are still calling everything on the main thread, so it's probably blocking it. Do you NEED to call those methods on the main thread?

Comment: I don't think they all need to be on the main thread... I just want the `showInstructions` to not freeze. Advice?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should never do any UI updates on a background thread.

Comment: Does that include adding annotations to a map?

Comment: Yes. In that case, let the background operation return an NSArray back to the main thread, then add the NSArray to the MKMapView synchronously.

Comment: Thanks Chris... back to my original question: Why is the thread locking `showInstruction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try calling -(void)loadEverything in "performSelectorOnMainThread" and from that call [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:] for operation which are not affecting UI components and [self performSelector] for which are affecting UI components.

Comment: Hi Learner, I'm now getting the error `*** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0xe05c260 of class NSCFString autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking` and my map annotations do not load.

Comment: Are you sure I can use NSThreads inside a `performSelectorOnMainThread`?

Comment: I am sure about usage of above method. In present code you are proving pool in only 'loadEverything' (I am assuming that based on above code). Try proving  separate autorelease pool in each method you are calling from thread. Moreover check your program in instruments. If memory is not increasing because of leaking pool then then rest is fine.

Comment: hi, read following for better understanding of auto release pool. [AutoreleasePool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7286685/need-clarification-for-nsautoreleasepool)

Comment: Hi Learner, I tried what you suggested.. but still didn't work.. I've updated my question with my current code. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn some GCD and do the same code inside a block. Or use an NSOperation… Avoid threads if possible.

Comment: I'll take a look. What's the reason for avoiding threads? Just curious.